# Is there any way to make a youtube video start buffering, without autoplay?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, html5-video

I have a website that plays back videos using the html5 video tag and the javascript api for the video tag, and also plays back youtube videos using the youtube javascript api.  I notice a bug on some browsers for youtube videos - when I seek to a certain point and play (all this in response to a user click on a button) the video doesn't seek.  It plays from the beginning.
This is not a problem for videos played back with the html5 video tag.  I think the reason that it is not a problem is that I use the "preload" option with that tag, which means that the video is mostly loaded and buffered before the user even clicks the button that does the SEEK.
So to get it to work with youtube, I need an equivalent of a "preload", or, perhaps I can make autoplay true, but then pause the video after a millisecond, just to get the buffering started.
Is there some solution to this that I don't know about?

Answer (score 0):

Which function are you using to do the seeking? It sounds a little like you might be using "playVideoAt()" -- with that function, if you specify a time beyond what is loaded, then it is expected behavior for it to start to play at the beginning. If, however, you're using the "seekTo()" method, then it shouldn't be doing that ... seekTo() should allow playing beyond what is loaded without a problem.

Another possibility would be to see if the "allowSeekAhead" parameter (to the "seekTo()" method) is being set or not.

Comment: I was  using seekto, and it does cause a problem, but only the very first time it is used.  So now I've solved the problem as follows: When the player is created, I do a small seek, and then in the playing event that is eventually fired, I pause the video.  This solves the problem, though as you say, it should not be a problem.